# How to avoid mistakes in functions with same type arguments

Tags: c++, function, function-declaration

How can I avoid mistakes with passing parameters of same type to function?

Let's consider function reading some binary data:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> read(size_t offset, size_t amount);
```

It's so easy to mistake offset with amount(I did similar it many times).

I see solution to this:

```
struct Offset
{
    explicit Offset(size_t value) : value{value}{}
    size_t value;
};
struct Amount
{
    explicit Amount(size_t value) : value{value}{}
    size_t value;
};
std::vector<uint8_t> read(Offset offset, Amount amount);
```

Is there a better solution to avoid mistakes like that?

Comment: This is largely about what people might consider good programming style, which is very opinionated. (The approach you mention is a common one though).

Comment: Why is this also tagged C?

Comment: I second the opinionated. "better" in terms of what?

Comment: @user463035818 In terms of less likely to get the arguments the wrong way round?

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches I can think of.

### Tagged Types

This is essentially what you are suggesting in your question, but I would implement it generically.

```
template <typename Tag, typename T>
struct Tagged
{
  explicit Tagged(const T& value) : value{value} { }
  T value;
};

template <typename Tag, typename T>
Tagged<Tag, T> tag(const T& value)
{
  return Tagged<Tag, T>{value};
}

struct OffsetTag
{ };
struct AmountTag
{ };

using Offset = Tagged<OffsetTag, std::size_t>;
using Amount = Tagged<AmountTag, std::size_t>;

std::vector<uint8_t> read(Offset offset, Amount amount);
```

This allows you to expand the same concept to other underlying data types.

### Named Parameter Idiom

The [Named Parameter Idiom](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/named-parameter-idiom.html) is somewhat similar to the `Options` approach in @PaulBelanger's answer, but it can be used in place and doesn't allow the user to take the the curly-brace shortcut that brings you back to the same problem you had before.  However, it will default-initialize all your parameters, so while you are protected from mixing up parameters, it can't force you to provide explicit values for all of them. For your example:

```
class ReadParams
{
public:
  ReadParams() : m_offset{0}, m_amount{128}
  { }

  ReadParams& offset(std::size_t offset)
  {
    m_offset = offset;
    return *this;
  }

  // Could get rid of this getter if you can make the users
  // of this class friends.
  std::size_t offset() const { return m_offset; }

  ReadParams& amount(std::size_t amount)
  {
    m_amount = amount;
    return *this;
  }

  // Could get rid of this getter if you can make the users
  // of this class friends.
  std::size_t amount() const { return m_amount; }

private:
  std::size_t m_offset;
  std::size_t m_amount;
};

std::vector<uint8_t> read(const ReadParams& params);

int main()
{
  read(ReadParams{}.offset(42).amount(2048)); // clear parameter names
  // read(ReadParams{42, 2048});              // won't compile
  read(ReadParams{}.offset(42));              // also possible, amount uses default value
}
```

You could implement the members of `ReadParams` as `std::optional`s and throw a runtime error if an uninitialized member is access; but you can no longer enforce *at compile time* that the user actually provides all parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that you can do is to pass parameters in a structure. This also allows you to set sensible defaults for the values. This is especially useful when a constructor takes a large number of arguments. For example:

```
class FooService
{
public:
    // parameters struct.
    struct Options
    {
        ip::address listen_address = ip::address::any();
        uint16_t port = 1337;
        bool allow_insecure_requests = false;
        std::string base_directory  = "/var/foo/"
    };
    //constructor takes the options struct to pass values. 
    explicit FooService(FooServiceOptions options);
    // ...
};
```

Which is then used like:

```
FooService::Options o;
o.port = 1338;
//all other values keep their defaults. 

auto service = make_unique<FooService>(o);
```

Comment: this is fine until someone considers it too tedious to set each field seperately and writes a constructor for `Options` that lets you pass all parameters ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, people would be inclined to write it as `FooService({ip::address::any(), 1337, ...})`. C99 style initializers would be helpful here, but they're not in C++ yet: `FooService({.port = 1337})`.

Comment: oh that's right! Apparently designated initializers are coming in C++20, so that can be an almost transparent solution for named parameters at that point!